# Why can't I get gain parallelization benefits with more processes?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I have this simple code that simply computes a sum of matrices after some matrix multiplication

```
def serial_decohere(K, rho, n):
"""
:param K: List of bumpy matrices of size 2^n by 2^n
:param rho: A matrix of size 2^n by 2^n
:param n: Integer
:return: A matrix of size 2^n by 2^n
"""
    out = np.zeros((pow(2, n), pow(2, n)), dtype=complex)
    for i in range(len(K)):
        out += np.dot(K[i], np.dot(rho, op.ctranspose(K[i])))
    return out
```

The number of terms in the sum grows exponentially with the variable n. More specifically the length of the list K grows like 3^n. So I decided to parallelize it. Using joblib I came with this

```
def decohere(K, rho, n):
"""
:param K: List of matrices of size 2^n by 2^n
:param rho: A matrix of size 2^n by 2^n
:param n: A positive integer
:return: A matrix of size 2^n by 2^n
"""
    out = np.zeros((pow(2, n), pow(2, n)), dtype=complex)
    def apply_kraus_op(kraus, rho_s):
        """
        :param rho_s : Density matrix of system rho_s
        :return: returns the density matrix 
        """
        nonlocal out
        out += np.dot(kraus, np.dot(rho_s, op.ctranspose(kraus)))

   Parallel(n_jobs=2)((delayed(apply_kraus_op))(K[i], rho) for i in range(len(K)))

return out
```

Then decided to test it. For n_jobs=1, and for matrices of size less than 32 by 32, I am better of with the first version. But quickly, the computation time for the second version grows more slowly so that I am better off with the second. Now when I increase to n_jobs=2, I am always slower than the first version. So that I am worse off parallelizing the for loop. Why? I could try to write code and using multiprocessing module but I am assuming the joblib took a lot more thought and time and is essentially doing that to parallelize the for loop.

Comment: What platform are you running this code on? And how large of an `n` are you working with?

Comment: @duskwuff Running on a Macbook Pro with 8 cores. The largest n I have tested is 7.

Comment: When someone asks "why is parallelization not speeding up my code", the answer is almost always "because your task is too small and the overhead of multiple processes outweighs the gain of simultaneous processing".

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you noted that "The largest `n` I have tested is 7".

The data you're working with here is *tiny*. Even with `n=7`, your matrix only has 128x128 = 65536 elements. The cost of starting up a new Python process to run work in parallel is significant; at such a small size, it's faster to just do all the work in a single process.

Try again with a much larger matrix… say, `n=12`.